# Массовая замена в Sublime при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Есть строка

> Lorem ipsum "dolor sit amet", consectetur "adipisicing" elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "dolore magna aliqua".

регулярное выражение `"(.+?)"` ищет вместе с `"`
Как исключить `"` из поиска?

Comment: `(?<=").+?(?=")` если там конечно работает просмотр назад и вперед. Или лучше `(?<=")[^"]+(?=")` Хотя, лишнее находит в тексте.

Comment: Спасибо. Почти то, что нужно. Не подскажете как теперь от "лишнего" в поиске избавиться?

Comment: Сразу на ум ни чего не приходит.

Comment: Так. Если вы речь ведете про замену, то почему не захватывать кавычки и не ставить их вместе с новым текстом? Тогда ни каких проблем не будет.

Comment: @sv458 Объясните, что вы делаете, как должен выглядеть конечный результат.

Comment: Вообще, Я просто изучаю регулярные выражения. Но результотом хотел бы видеть: замену всего, что между кавычками на другой текст